# plotly dash: How to get headline of csv as options for dropdown

Tags: csv, callback, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am writing a dash-app. 
At the moment my app looks like this

`

```
import base64
import io
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table_experiments as dt
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash()
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),



#plot dropdowns graph and tabel     
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),  

    html.Div(dt.DataTable(rows=[{}]), style={'display': 'none'}),

            ],

          )
#%%methodes 
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')),sep=';',header=6)
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),sep=';',header=6)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])
    available_indicators=list(df)
    ind =np.delete(available_indicators,0),
    print (ind)
    return html.Div([
            #x-Achse
        html.Div('Choose Data for x-axis'),
        dcc.RadioItems(
                id='x_Achse',
                    options=[
                        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ind[0]],
        ),
            #y-Achse
        html.Label('Choose Data for y-axis'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='y-Achse',
                options=[
                        {'label': i, 'value': i}for i in ind[0]],
                multi= True
        ),
        #Graph
        return_graph(df,1,1),
        html.H5(filename),
        # Use the DataTable prototype component:
        # github.com/plotly/dash-table-experiments
        dt.DataTable(rows=df.to_dict('records')),
        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

#%%
def return_graph(df, x_Werte, Y_Werte_Array):
 return dcc.Graph(id='Liniendiagramm',
               figure={
               'data': [go.Scatter(
                            x=df['Date/Time'],   #change to x_Werte
                            y=df['Var_01'],      #change to Y_Werte_Array[0]
                            text=df['Var_01'],   #change to Y_Werte_Array[0]
                            name='Var_01'        #change to Y_Werte_Array[0]
                            ),

                        go.Scatter(
                            x=df['Date/Time'],   #change to x_Werte
                            y=df['Var_02'],      #change to Y_Werte_Array[1]
                            text=df['Var_02'],   #change to Y_Werte_Array[1]
                            name='Var_02'        #change to Y_Werte_Array[1]
                            ),    
                        ]   
                    }
               )
#%%

#end Methoden            
#%%callback
@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename'),
               Input('upload-data', 'last_modified')])
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d,) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]        
        return children

#%%      
  if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)`
```

Now my Problem. 
The dropdowns in my app are in the methode parse_contents. So I get an error, if I try to use a callback to get the value of the dropdowns. The options for the dropdowns are calculate amongst other things in this methode. 
I need a solution to get the headline of a Tabel in a .csv flie. Use the values of the headline as options for the dropdowns and write the selected Values of the dropdowns in the methode return_graph .

Finaly it's has to look so
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ96g.png)
but at the moment the both dropdowns are useless and the graph is ploted by  static values
Sorry for the german words in the code, and the bad english.

Answer (score 1):

So now I have a solution for my problem. If Someone want to use it, here is the code. Please note, that in the methode "parse content" the parameters sep=';' and header=6 lines, are set as static parameters.

```
`import base64
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_table_experiments as dte
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash
import pandas as pd
import io



app = dash.Dash()

app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H5("Upload Files"),
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },

    ),


    html.Br(),
    html.Div("X_Achse"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='x_Achse',
        multi = False,
        placeholder='Filter Column'),
    html.Div('Y_Werte'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='y_Achse',
        multi = True,
        placeholder='Filter Column'),

    html.Div(id='graph'),
    html.Br(),
    html.H5("Updated Table"),
    html.Div(dte.DataTable(rows=[{}], id='table'))
    ])
# Functions
#%%
# file upload function
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')),sep=';',header=6)
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),sep=';',header=6)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    return df
#%%
def return_graph(df, x_Werte, Y_Werte_Array):
    return dcc.Graph(id='Liniendiagramm',
               figure={
               'data': [                   #definiert die Daten welche visualisiert werden sollen
                       go.Scatter(
                            x=df[x_Werte],
                            y=df[Y_Werte_Array[i]],
                            text=df[Y_Werte_Array[i]],
                            name=Y_Werte_Array[i]                           
                            )
                       for i in range(0,len(Y_Werte_Array))
                        ]   
                    }
               )
#%%
@app.callback(Output('graph','children'),
              [Input('x_Achse','value'),
               Input('y_Achse','value'),
               Input('table','rows')])
def update_graph(x,y,c): 
    if x and y and c is not None:
        print (x)
        print (y)
#        print (c)
        dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c)
#        print('anfang')
#        print(dff)
#        print ('ende')
        graph1=return_graph(dff,x,y)
#       print (c)    
        return graph1 #return_graph(c,a,b)
#%%
# callback table creation
@app.callback(Output('table', 'rows'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        if df is not None:
           # print (df)
            return df.to_dict('records')
        else:
            return [{}]
    else:
        return [{}]
#%%
#callback update options of filter dropdown
@app.callback(Output('x_Achse', 'options'),
              [Input('table', 'rows')])
def update_x_Achse( tablerows):
    if tablerows is not None: 
        dff = pd.DataFrame(tablerows) # <- problem! dff stays empty even though table was uploaded

        print ("updating... dff empty?:"), dff.empty #result is True, labels stay empty

        return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in sorted(list(dff))]
#%%
@app.callback(Output('y_Achse', 'options'),
              [Input('table', 'rows')])
def update_y_Achse( tablerows):
    if tablerows is not None: 
        dff = pd.DataFrame(tablerows) # <- problem! dff stays empty even though table was uploaded

        print ("updating... dff empty?:"), dff.empty #result is True, labels stay empty

        return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in sorted(list(dff))]
#%%

app.css.append_css({
    "external_url": "https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)`
```

Comment: how can I achieve this without using the table as source for columns?
I would like to fill the dropdown directly with content from my dataframe (xlsx from input field)